# Completablefuture - Como usar?

Tags: java, java-8, assincronismo

Nesta situação, como é que devo trabalhar com o CompletableFuture?

Utilizando o método de **WorldCupSocialApi** implemente o método `CompletableFuture<Stream<String>> getMostPopularTeamNames(int maxResults)`, onde maxResults indica o número máximo de resultados que se pretende obter. Por exemplo, para obter os nomes das 5 seleções mais populares, o método deve ser invocado com maxResults = 5.

```
class WorldCupSocialApi { 
// Invoca o callback teamsConsumer com a lista de nomes das seleções mais 
// populares, com as posições de popularidade from e to. 
// Exº para obter as 5 seleções mais populares, este método deve ser invocado 
// com from = 1 e to = 5. Caso não existam seleções nesse intervalo, é 
// invocado com uma lista vazia.


public static void getMostPopularTeamNames(int from, int to, Consumer<List<String>> teamsConsumer); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CompletableFuture<Stream<String>> getMostPopularTeamNames(int maxResults){
    CompletableFuture<Stream<String>> mostPopularTeamNames;
    WorldCupSocialApi.getMostPopularTeamNames(1, maxResults, (teams) -> {
        mostPopularTeamNames = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> teams.stream());
    });
    return mostPopularTeamNames;
}
```